# Wordpress webiste migration from AWS to GCP

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, migration

I migrated my old website from AWS to GCP. I transferred media files from AWS S3 to GCP bucket.

Problems : Wordpress admin is not showing all transferred images after connecting to GCP.  If i upload new images its working fine and uploading on same bucket , but existing are not showing . Permission is also public . Any help or guidance.

Tried couple of option from internet and chatGPT, some plugin like WP offload

Comment: You might receive a better response at: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: WordPress doesn't support saving images to S3 or GCP buckets by default. You would have had to use a plugin for that. The plugin would have to track what images had been uploaded to S3 and know when to rewrite the URLs for those images accordingly. The issue you are encountering right now is probably an issue with the plugin you are/were using. Reading your question you seem to indicate you don't know if you were even using a plugin for that previously. You need to figure that out. This isn't a programming question.